# Using alarmManager when broadcastReceiver doesn't work

Tags: android

I have a problem with my broadcast receiver, everything is work but after few hours android 5.0.1 is killing this proccess. This broadcast is receiving phone calls. Is any way to solve this problem? I think that I should use AlarmManager and wake up this broadcast every day. What is the best option to use this alarm manager in this broadcast receiver?

```
    public class IncCall extends BroadcastReceiver {
           @Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

 String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                    Log.d("debug","state: " + state);

                }
            }
```

Manifest:

```
        <receiver android:name="IncCall"
                  android:enabled="true"
                  android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: also why are trying to get telephonemanager state

Comment: because I'm waiting for incoming call

Comment: then why are you using package install action

Comment: Because I found information, that this could helped for it.

Comment: no that wont help check my updated manifest

Answer (score 0):

use a manifest something like this:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.example.MyCallReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: Do you think that it could solve my problem? :) I added this line, but I must wait few hours by check is this working.

Comment: try installing an app and see if broadcast works, becoz same code is working for me

Comment: also are you trying to get call state or app install uninstall state?

Comment: use alarmManager to wake it up or use  a service and also try raising the proirity of your broadcast

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this in manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" >
</uses-permission>
```